# Validation of POST vars returns incorrect values

Tags: php

I am a new programmer and I tried a bunch of different ways to validate my code and clearly am doing it totally wrong. Any help would be appreciated. I am still working on validating just the name. This version clearly doesn't make sense but i couldn't get it to work any way I try.

```
  <?php

require_once ('includes/classes/database.php');
require_once('includes/classes/user.php');
require_once('includes/header.php');


// if user submits a new registration
if (isset($_POST['name'],$_POST['email'],$_POST['pwd'],$_POST['pwd2']))
{
    if(strlen(trim($_POST['name'])) <= 20)
    { 
        return (true);
        return $name;
    }
    else
    {
        return (false);
    }

    // validate input fields
    //$name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $password = $_POST['pwd'];
    $password2 = $_POST['pwd2'];

    // if error fall through and redisplay page with errors

    // if no errors update database and redirect to homepage
    if ($uc->add_member($name, $email, $password) === FALSE)
    {
        echo "System Error. damn if I know what to do";
    } 
    else
    {
        header("location: homepage.php");
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: what does not works for you? always getting a true ?

Comment: sorry, yes its always returning true and adding to the database no matter what I try. I want to make sure the name is less than 20 characters and if it isnt I want it to stop from inserting into the database and send an error message back to the same page saying that the name must be less than 20 characters

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something but the code after `if(strlen(trim($_POST['name'])) <= 20)` is never executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (strlen(trim($_POST['name']))<=20)
{ 
    return (true);    }
else
{
    return (false);
}
```

Just get the return name out. Then it will work.

Comment: @Akos: `return $name;` is just ignored anyway, as the program ends on `return true`.

Comment: @Mike: How does this run any differently than your current code?

Answer (score 3):

```
if(strlen(trim($_POST['name'])) <= 20)
    { 
        return (true);
        return $name;
    }
    else
    {
        return (false);
    }
```

PHP ends the function once it hits a `return` statement.  This will either make it return with `TRUE` or `FALSE` depending the length of the name.  The rest of the program after this will not run.

Also, you cannot have 2 return statements like that.

```
return (true);
return $name;
```

Will return `TRUE` and `return $name` will not get ran.

Answer (score 1):

This is strange code.

As someone else pointed out, the double return thing won't work.

Also, the === false part is suspect, are you checking if it evaluates as false, or is actually false, the === is probably too much, == would probably do the job. You've not posted any code from that class for us to check if the === is OK in this case.

Make some changes to it, and try to post actual questions about actual problems, rather than "This isn't quite right, can you debug the entire script?".